# 404 page not working on website, help me to sort out Htaccess issue

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, broken-links

I have removed this post from our database entirely but the below link is still showing blank template instead of 404 not found error,

http://www.myconsumercourt.com/complaints/online-shopping/men-clothing/complaint-against-livastar-backlift-technologies-pvt-ltd-1421.html

here is my .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php    
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^complaints/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)-(.*).html$  post-info.php?ticket-number=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^complaints/(.*)/(.*)$   query-listing.php?sub-category=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^complaints/(.*)$   subject-list.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Please help me to redirect my broken page to 404.php page.

Thank you so much.
Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

This is because  your first RewriteRule is rewriting this url to an existent file.

put the following rule bellow "RewriteEngine on" line to redirect the url to 404.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /complaints/online-shopping/men-clothing/complaint-against-livastar-backlift-technologies-pvt-ltd-1421\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The solution is only for this link.We have many dynamic  links which are broken in our database . So it is not possible to add each and every link separately into .htaccess file.

Comment: Yes,this is possible, you can write multiple rules for your broken urls

Comment: Thank again Starkeen, Your solution worked like charm but is it possible to add any .htaccess code to redirect these page automatically. Another problem is, the below link is live and healthy. but this link is also not re-directing to 404 page, if you click and modify this link randomly after myconsumercourt.com/complaints/....  

http://www.myconsumercourt.com/complaints/others/consumer-complaints/money-not-releasing-from-sahar-9579.html